# Adding native static dependencies

Tags: c++, gradle, native, dependency-management, build.gradle

In a C++ Gradle project, I use the boost 1.49 library.

How can I add this library as dependency of my project.

I try in this way, but I should define boost as dependency. There is a C++ library repository?

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

libraries {
    hello {
        baseName 'hello'
    }
}

sources {
    hello{
        cpp {
            source.srcDirs = ['src']
            lib library: 'boost', linkage: 'api' 
            exportedHeaders.srcDirs = ['include']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c/cpp programming is not but domain (in contrast to gradle ;) ) but when you navigate to `$GRADLE_HOME/samples/native-binaries` you can find lots of useful examples there.

One of them - *cunit* (oh, there's a another one: *multi-project*) has such configuration - it may be useful for you. Below I enclose `build.gradle` from *cunit* - in case you use gradle wrapper.

```
apply plugin: "c"
apply plugin: "cunit"

model {
    flavors {
        passing
        failing
    }
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            cunit {
                headers.srcDir "lib/cunit/2.1-2/include"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile =
                        file("lib/cunit/2.1-2/lib/" +
                             findCUnitLibForPlatform(targetPlatform))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

libraries {
    operators {}
}
binaries.withType(CUnitTestSuiteBinarySpec) {
    lib library: "cunit", linkage: "static"

    if (flavor == flavors.failing) {
        cCompiler.define "PLUS_BROKEN"
    }
}

def findCUnitLibForPlatform(Platform platform) {
    if (platform.operatingSystem.windows) {
        return "vs2010/cunit.lib"
//        return "vs2013/cunit.lib"
//        return "cygwin/cunit.lib"
//        return "mingw/cunit.lib"
    } else if (platform.operatingSystem.macOsX) {
        return "osx/libcunit.a"
    } else {
        return "linux/libcunit.a"
    }
}
```

Quick googling has shown that there's no such thing like a libraries repository for c/cpp projects. It seems that the libraries should be included in project sources.